# System really limited by disk IO? Rate in atop much lower than expected

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance, raid-1

I have a system with two 2TByte SATA disks configured as a Raid1 array.

There are times when the cpu is waiting for I/O for more than 20% of the time (output from `sar`) e.g.

```
09:25:01        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
09:35:01        all     57,65      0,00      6,53     25,54      0,05     10,23
15:45:01        all      0,90      0,00      1,47     54,90      0,06     42,68
15:55:04        all      1,74      0,00      1,58     88,52      0,10      8,06
16:25:03        all      0,59      0,00      0,38     24,14      0,05     74,84
23:45:05        all      2,45      0,00      1,43     31,56      0,05     64,50
```

I collected additional information using `atop` which shows, that disk-I/O on one of the raid-disks is at the upper limit (disk sda, busy to 90%)  e.g.:

```
MDD | md1 | busy 0% | | read 10174 | write 425 | | KiB/r 6 | KiB/w 7 | MBr/s 1.2 | | MBw/s 0.1 | avq 0.00 | | avio 0.00 ms |
DSK | sda | busy 90% | | read 9091 | write 507 | | KiB/r 6 | KiB/w 7 | MBr/s 0.9 | | MBw/s 0.1 | avq 1.14 | | avio 5.65 ms |
DSK | sdb | busy 18% | | read 1082 | write 507 | | KiB/r 11 | KiB/w 7 | MBr/s 0.2 | | MBw/s 0.1 | avq 1.39 | | avio 6.82 ms |
```

The man-page to `atop` states:

> Such line shows the name (e.g. VolGroup00-lvtmp for a logical volume
>   or sda for a hard disk), the busy percentage i.e. the portion of time
>   that the unit was busy handling requests (busy), the number of read
>   requests issued (read), the number of write requests issued
>   (write), the number of KiBytes per read (KiB/r), the number of
>   KiBytes per write (KiB/w), the number of MiBytes per second
>   throughput for reads (MBr/s), the number of MiBytes per second
>   throughput for writes (MBw/s), the average queue depth (avq) and
>   the average number of milliseconds needed by a request (avio) for
>   seek, latency and data transfer.

Information can be read in parallel from both disks for raid1, but this is not used for a single stream of sequential input according to the `md` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/4/md) , explaining the fact that the second disk is not fully used

Looking at the MBr/s and MBw/s entries for sda, it looks like the disk is 90% busy with

0.9 + 0.1  MiBytes per second = 1 MiBytes per second = 8 MiBit per second

However, the [expected rate for current disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Data_transfer_rate) is on the order of 1000 Mbit/s, which is roughly 100 times higher (neglecting the conversion from MiBit to Mbit).

The disks are (ouput of `hdparm -I /dev/sda`)

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
Model Number: TOSHIBA DT01ACA200
Serial Number: 54A8UH4GS
Firmware Revision: MX4OABB0
Transport: Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0; Revision: ATA8-AST T13 Project D1697 Revision 0b
Standards:
Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029)
Supported: 8 7 6 5
Likely used: 8
Configuration:
Logical max current
cylinders 16383 16383
heads 16 16
sectors/track 63 63
--
CHS current addressable sectors: 16514064
LBA user addressable sectors: 268435455
LBA48 user addressable sectors: 3907029168
Logical Sector size: 512 bytes
Physical Sector size: 4096 bytes
Logical Sector-0 offset: 0 bytes
device size with M = 1024*1024: 1907729 MBytes
device size with M = 1000*1000: 2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
cache/buffer size = unknown
Form Factor: 3.5 inch
Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
Capabilities:
LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
Queue depth: 32
Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16 Current = 16
Advanced power management level: disabled
DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6
Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4
Cycle time: no flow control=120ns IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
Enabled Supported:
* SMART feature set
Security Mode feature set
* Power Management feature set
* Write cache
* Look-ahead
* Host Protected Area feature set
* WRITE_BUFFER command
* READ_BUFFER command
* NOP cmd
* DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
Advanced Power Management feature set
Power-Up In Standby feature set
* SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
SET_MAX security extension
* 48-bit Address feature set
* Device Configuration Overlay feature set
* Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
* FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
* SMART error logging
* SMART self-test
Media Card Pass-Through
* General Purpose Logging feature set
* WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
* 64-bit World wide name
* URG for READ_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
* URG for WRITE_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
* WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
* {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
* Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
* unknown 119[7]
* Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
* Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
* Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
* Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
* Host-initiated interface power management
* Phy event counters
* NCQ priority information
Non-Zero buffer offsets in DMA Setup FIS
* DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
Device-initiated interface power management
In-order data delivery
* Software settings preservation
* SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
* SCT Write Same (AC2)
* SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
* SCT Features Control (AC4)
* SCT Data Tables (AC5)
Security:
Master password revision code = 65534
supported
not enabled
not locked
frozen
not expired: security count
not supported: enhanced erase
320min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000039ffac402a6
NAA : 5
IEEE OUI : 000039
Unique ID : ffac402a6
Checksum: correct
```

Is the output or the man-page for `atop` wrong or are the hard disks underperforming very much compared to the expected value or is there a missunderstanding on my side?

Or the wider question is: is my system really limited by the disk I/O capacity?

Comment: Mechanical HDDs have extremely low IOPS (often ~10), and while there's a significant relative increase on higher 10 - 15k RPM datacenter HDDs, it's still painfully low when compared to SSDs (~50K - 500K).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected **sequential** rate for current disks is on the order of 1000 Mbit/s, but this does not change anything for **random** IO.

A 7200 RPM disk will do around 120 random IOPS. So in a worst case scenario, where you always write only 1 byte, you will end up with a throughput of 120 Bytes/s.

Yes, this means, that there are around 6 decimal orders of magnitude between best case (only sequential) and worst case. Your result of 1KByte/s is somewhere in between, but much closer to the worst case.

You would profit very much from using an SSD: Even a small one when used as a `bcache` or `LV cache` can increase your random IOPS (especially those painfull small writes) by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Time to start pricing reliable SSDs.

Comment: Especially when there's no comparison for IOPS between an SSD [~50K - 500K] and an HDD [~10]